# How do I assign roles and set permissions on each method in Java?

Tags: java, sql

I'm developing a application for Computer Lab Management System, this is my assignment. I'm using SQL Server to write SQL Script, and manage my databases, and I use netbeans to write Java source code and interact to SQL Server via JDBC.

I want to role and set permission for each method in my application. Example:
Admin can View/Add/Edit/Remove a User
User can only View the records.

void view(), add(), edit(), remove can be used by admin. But, void view() can only used by user, and user can't use methods: add(), edit(). I tried search, read some book, looking for some article for my trouble.But, ... no article i found!

Thank you for your readiing!

Comment: This is more a design question than anything. You don't limit a method to a user role per se.

Comment: I agree with @Tyler. You need to come up with a design that will enforce the requirements given for the assignment. Perhaps you can start with a `Role` interface and provide concrete classes for it.

Answer (score 1):

Since Admin, User , etc  are Roles rather than explicit users I would suggest using the Role Pattern.
Here a little example:

```
class User{
UserRole role;
//other user concerning stuff
}  

abstract class UserRole{
//eg. every User has at least the View Permission    
abstract void view();
//If the view() Operation should behave the way for every role, implement it right here
}

class AdminRole extends UserRole{
   public void add(){}
   public void view(){}
   public void edit(){}
   public void remove(){}
}

class EditRole extends UserRole{
   public void view(){}
   public void edit(){}
}
```

This way you isolate the User and its Permissions and you can change the Role during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can't define "permissions" on methods. 
You can instead use OOP to represent the object of your domain. Each object could represent an entity in your permission system, implementing the methods it's supposed to be allowed to use.

For example:

```
class Admin
{
   public void Add(){}
   public void View(){}
   public void Edit(){}
   public void Remove(){}
}


class User
{
   public void View(){}

}
```

Like others pointed out, this is most a design issue. The too much simple solution proposed before doesn't scale very well :) (what if you need to dynamically change permission?What if different permission should be granted to different user?)

This of course depend on the complexity and the requirements of your homework. If you need a more elegant and flexible solution to manage permission you can have a look at [RBAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control) (Role Based Access Control).

Note that mine isn't a real answer, just some hints. Hope to be helpful anyway.